# docker mount volume dir ubuntu

Tags: docker, mount, docker-volume

I'm trying to use docker to do this:

> Run Docker image, make sure you mount your User (for MAC) or home (for
>   Ubuntu) directory as a volume so you can access your local files

The code that I've been given is:

```
docker run -v /Users/:/host -p 5000:5000 -t -i bjoffe/openface_flask_v2  /bin/bash
```

I know that the part that I should modify to my local files is `-v /Users/:/host`, but I am unsure how to do so.

The files I want to load in the container are inside `home/user/folder-i-want-to-read`

How should this code be written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bind mount is just a mapping of the host files or directories into a container files or directories. That basically pointing to the same physical location on disk. 
In your case, you could try this command,

```
docker container run -it -p 5000:5000 -v /home/user/folder-i-want-to-read/:/path_in_container bjoffe/openface_flask_v2 /bin/bash
```

And, once run verify that directories from the path on host `home/user/folder-i-want-to-read` are loaded in the container path which you have mapped.